# Giving variable @Dblookup value

Tags: xpages

I have the following code:

```
var x = @DbLookup("", "(category)", getComponent("model").getValue(),2);
getComponent("test").Value = x;
```

The @Dblookup works fine, but I'm wondering is it possible to give a variable the lookup result?

Oh and yes, the `getComponent("test").Value = x;` give me error.

EDIT: Another question? What does the @DbLookup even return? I tried to display x[0] and still got the error, so I guess it's not a array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. There are a few amendments that would make it cleaner for you.

Firstly, for the first parameter of the @DbLookup, "" has been best practice for Notes Client development, but @DbName() is best practice for XPages. If you ever have to develop for XPiNC, you'll find "" doesn't work there.

I'd recommend adding the final parameter `"[FAILSILENT]"`. Because this is SSJS that gets compiled to Java, you can't just use [FAILSILENT], you need to pass a String, so "[FAILSILENT]". I'm not sure what the @DbLookup does in XPages if it hits an error, but this will ensure you definitely get a blank string back, which is what you want.

Tim Tripcony always used to say go to the data model, not the components. Your components are bound to the data model, and before your SSJS can run, that data model will have been updated (though changes not saved back to the underlying document in the NSF). So it's easier and cleaner to just use e.g. `doc.getItemValueString("model")` and `doc.replaceItemValueString("test")`.

The reason the `.Value()` line is failing is because that's not the method name, it's `setValue()`. For all the properties on a component, you can access that property via code by capitalising the first letter and adding `get` or `set` in front, e.g. `getValue()`, `setValue()`, `getStyleClass()`, `setStyleClass()` etc. If you want to use the component, the SSJS editor has a library to get to current components, which will cast them to the correct Java datatype and gives you the typeahead.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I still have no results, I get "Error 500" and I don't understand what am i doing wrong.
var x = @DbLookup("", "(category)", getComponent("model").getValue(),2, "[FAILSILENT]");
getComponent("test").setValue() = x;

Comment: Try  putting the individual parts of your dblookup into variables and verify that they're valid eg getComponent("model").getValue() - if for example there's some issue with getting that value it'sll make it look like the dblookup failed whereas it's just the dblookup was passed duff info

Comment: Got that part running, found the problem. Code: var x = @DbLookup("", "(p_kategorija)", getComponent("pirk_modelis").getValue(),2, "[FAILSILENT]");
getComponent("test").setValue(x);

Comment: Bind your UI to variables and access those. in mvc we access m not v.